# Definition of $p$-variation of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have two definition of the $p$-variation of a function :

> **Def 1:** $$\operatorname{Var}_p(f,t)=\sup_{\Pi}\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n |f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|^p\mid \Pi:0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=t\right\},$$
> where $\Pi$ is a partition of $[0,t]$.

and

> **Def 2:** Let $\Pi_n:0=t_0^n<t_1^n<\cdots<t_m^n=t$ a partition of $[0,t]$ s.t. $|\Pi_n|\to 0$.
>
> $$\operatorname{var}_p(f,t):=\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^n |f(t_{i-1})-f(t_i)|^p$$

**Question**

It's clear that if $\operatorname{var}_p(f,t)$ exists, then $\operatorname{Var}_p(f,t)\geq \operatorname{var}_p(f,t)$.

Q1) I think that if $\operatorname{var}_p(f,t)$ exists and $\operatorname{Var}_p(f,t)$ is finite, then both are equal, right ?

Q2) Also, what is the interest to have these two definitions ? In what $\operatorname{Var}_p(f,t)$ or $\operatorname{var}_p(f,t)$ is more or less useful ?

Comment: What here is the stochastic process? $f$? That is unusual notation.

Comment: @Math1000: Indeed, no need probability here

Answer (score 2):

The answer to you first question is negative: For example take
$$f(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \ge 1 \\ 1/2  & \text{ if } x \in [0,1) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}.$$
A simple calculation shows that $\mathrm{Var}_p(f,1) =1$, but $\mathrm{var}_p(f,1) = 2^{-p+1}$. Thus, for $p>1$ this definitions are different. In fact, in the second variant we are forced to consider the local behaviour of the function. Meanwhile, the first definition only analyze the overall variation.

In stochastic analysis it is natural to consider the second definition (more specifically, one should consider the $p$-th root of your definition), since you are interested (also from an application-oriented view) in understanding the local behaviour.